# SQL Metrics Use

Tags: sql, metrics

I was going through a sql query and I found someone used "metric1".

```
SELECT  'LTD' metric1,
b.ID
from TABLE1 as B
WHERE
B.REGION_ID = 4 ;
```

When i searched, I got something related to monitoring system but i am sure if that makes sense here .

Comment: it's called a column 'alias'. The 'AS' is optional in many RDBMS

Answer (score -1):

In this context, `metric1` is just the name of the column.  If you run the query, you will see that the first column is called `metric1`.

I recommend using `as` for defining column aliases:

```
SELECT 'LTD' as metric1, b.ID
FROM TABLE1 as B
WHERE B.REGION_ID = 4 ;
```

However, the `AS` is optional -- both in the standard in an almost all databases.

The reason I *always* use `AS` is to make it easier to spot when I leave out a comma.  So:

```
select x y
from t
```

returns one column, where the value is t.x but the name is y.

However,

```
select x, y
from t
```

returns two columns.

By *always* using `as` the first just looks wrong to me, so it is easier to spot if a comma is missing.